# Batch script to process media files

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am very happy to have found this place.

I have an external drive I use for my media and as I am switching to Kodi as my media player, there are some changes I need to make.

The drive has many many directories and in each directory there is an image file to accompany said media file.  Example:

```
filename1.mp3
filename1.jpg
```

Of course the filename varies as does the amount of files, though each file does have a respective image.  I need to recursively sweep the drive and have it make copies of whatever the jpg and the final result should be something like this:

```
filename1.mp3
filename1.jpg
filename1-poster.jpg
poster.jpg
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?  It's thousands of files so its really beyond the scope of doing this manually.

I do certainly appreciate any assistance or insight anybody can provide to accomplish this monumental task.

Best regards,

Peter

Comment: Hello again.  Anybody that has a solution to my problem, I would surely be grateful to help accomplish this monster task.  Cheers!

Comment: Hello, I am still stuck with my problem and really need to find someone that can assist me with a batch type process.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (unix shell, e.g. ksh, bash) and not necessarily safe against spaces in file names would be:

```
for file in $(find . -name '*.mp3') ; do
   base="${file%%.mp3}"
   cp "$base.jpg" "$base-poster.jpg"
   cp "$base.jpg" "$(dirname $base)/poster.jpg"
done
```

Comment: that's not batch. (if you give code in a different language as asked for, you should explicitely note that fact)

Comment: Explicitly noted that it is bash, not batch.

Comment: Many thanks for your response, achimh, appreciated.  I am using windows and yes, there will be spaces in filenames.  Also to note, everything is no mp3, there are mp4, avi, mkv, etc.